# Encrypt a symmetric AES key with RSA in Crypto++

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, crypto++

I'm trying to exchange an AES key between two parts.The AES key would be encrypted with receiver's RSA `publicKey` and then written to a file.

I'm using Crypto++ library,and here is the beginning of my program:

```
//generate key pair
CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
CryptoPP::RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor priv(rng, 4096);

RSA::PrivateKey privateKey(params);
RSA::PublicKey publicKey(params);

//generate aes key (256bits)
SecByteBlock key(AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
rnd.GenerateBlock(key, key.size());
```

(You will recognize Crypto++ wiki example)

Then I start the encryption routine:

```
CryptoPP::SecByteBlock cipher(CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH), decrypted_data(CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);

CryptoPP::RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor e(publicKey);
```

I don't know which one to use: `CryptoPP:: ArraySource` or `CryptoPP::StringSource`?

Comment: Well, an AES key consists of bytes/bits, so `ArraySource` should be more logical. The encryption of a key is also called key wrapping, but a quick search on the internet doesn't display any direct results. As Crypto++ is a software library there is little difference in encrypting bytes or a key, so that would explain the missing sample code for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... after I don't know what to use : CryptoPP::ArraySource ? CryptoPP::StringSource ?

After this, use a `PK_EncryptorFilter` for the RSA encryptor; and use an `ArraySource` for the key you are trying to encrypt. An `ArraySource` is just a typedef for a `StringSource`, so you are really just using a `StringSource`.

The code would look something like the following. I did not run the examples, so please fix the typos.

```
SecByteBlock key(AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
rng.GenerateBlock(key, key.size());
...

RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor encryptor(publicKey);
...

ArraySource as(key, key.size(), true, /* pump all data */
    new PK_EncryptorFilter(rng, encryptor,
        new FileSink("session-key.enc")));
```

You can write it to a `std::string` with something like:

```
std::string session_key;
ArraySource as(key, key.size(), true, /* pump all data */
    new PK_EncryptorFilter(rng, encryptor,
        new StringSink(session_key)));
```

You could also get fancy and use a `ByteQueue`. The `Redirector` breaks the ownership chain. Also see [`Redirector`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Redirector) on the Crypto++ wiki.

```
ByteQueue queue;
ArraySource as(key, key.size(), true, /* pump all data */
    new PK_EncryptorFilter(rng, encryptor,
        new Redirector(queue)));
```

`ByteQueue` are cool because they wrap `SecByteBlock`. Once in a `ByteQueue` you can move the bytes around with `TransferTo` and `CopyTo`:

```
ByteQueue queue;
ArraySource as(key, key.size(), true, /* pump all data */
    new PK_EncryptorFilter(rng, encryptor,
        new Redirector(queue)));

// Copy bytes to a file
FileSink sink1("session-key.enc");
queue.CopyTo(sink1);

// Copy bytes to std::out
HexEncoder encoder(new FileSink(std::cout));
queue.CopyTo(encoder);

// Transfer bytes to a SecByteBlock.
SecByteBlock block(queue.MaxRetrievable());
ArraySink sink2(block, block.size());
queue.TransferTo(sink2);
// No bytes remain in the queue
```

You might also be interested in [Pipelines](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining) on the Crypto++ wiki. The stuff you see above are sources, filters and sinks used in a pipeline.

---

If this is supposed to hold the encrypted symmetric key, then its too small:

```
SecByteBlock cipher(AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
```

Take a look at [RSA Encryption Schemes](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Encryption_Schemes) on the Crypto++ wiki. `cipher` needs to be `encryptor.CiphertextLength(AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);`, which is roughly the size of the RSA modulus minus about 50 bytes for the OAEP formatting and padding.

---

> (comment) > Now I am trying to add the part to decrypt it using the private key... Is this correct ?
>
> ```
> StringSource(readed_key, true,
>     new PK_DecryptorFilter(rng, decryptor, new 
>         FileSource("sessionkey.enc")));
> ```

Well, the filter part is correct (the `PK_DecryptorFilter` part). In Crypto++, data flows from a source to a sink. So the general pattern is as shown below. Its called a [Pipeline](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining).

```
Source(..., new Filter(..., new Filter(..., new Sink(...))));
```

Usually you want something like the following. The `Redirector` breaks the ownership chain. Also see [`Redirector`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Redirector) on the Crypto++ wiki.

```
// decrypted, in-memory
SecByteBlock session_key(AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
ArraySink sink(session_key, session_key.size());

FileSource fs("sessionkey.enc", true,
    new PK_DecryptorFilter(rng, decryptor, 
        new Redirector(sink)));
```

---

> (comment) > ... and then compare the original ...

You can compare two byte buffers in nearly constant time with [`VerifyBufsEqual`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/VerifyBufsEqual). Again, see the Crypto++ wiki.

Comment: Thank you ! yes,i wanted to use "cipher" to hold the aes key in encrypted form,but with your 1st example and FileSink i don't need it anymore ! I'm now trying to add the decryption part,that's to say read the key from "sessionkey.enc",decrypt it using the private key,and then compare the original and the decrypted key to check if all the process is correct. To read and decrypt the key,is that correct ? `
 CryptoPP::StringSource(readed_key, true, new CryptoPP::PK_DecryptorFilter(rng, decryptor, new CryptoPP::FileSource("sessionkey.enc")));` ,or do i need to use something else than FileSource ?